# QScrollBar + QScrollAera in QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qscrollarea

My question is simple : how can I set a QScrollBar in my QScrollArea. I have tested a lot of things but nothing work ... Maybe it's a problem to set a QScrollArea in a QTabWidget ? Here is the code :

```
void    GamesWindow::createTabSucces()
{
    std::string nameImg;

    _succesPage = new QWidget(_tab);
    _tab->addTab(_succesPage, "      Succes       ");

    scrollArea = new QScrollArea(_succesPage);
    scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
    scrollArea->setFixedSize(500,500);
    /*  Integration of QScrollBar  */
    for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++)
    {
        nameImg = "img/allAchiv/";
        nameImg += intToString(i + 1);
        nameImg += ".jpg";
        _imgSucc[i] = new QLabel(scrollArea);
        _imgSucc[i]->setPixmap(QPixmap(QString(nameImg.c_str())));
        _imgSucc[i]->setGeometry((14 + (85 * (i % 5))), 46 + ((i / 5) * 85), 60, 60);
    }
}
```

In fact, I add pictures in a tab where is created a QScrollArea (like 8-9 lines of pictures) but only 5 are visible, the others are hide, because they are at the bottom, out of the defined zone.

Any idea ? Thank's.

Answer (score 1):

You must:

- add a layout to your page (`QVBoxLayout`)
- add the scroll area to that page layout
- add a layout to the `viewport()` widget in the scroll area (`QVBoxLayout`)
- add your QLabels to that viewport layout

This way you won't need to call setGeometry on each label

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a widget to your scroll area and add your pictures to the widget's layout. Check [QScrollArea::setWidget(QWidget *widget)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html#setWidget)

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure that you can't add scroll to a tab widget but my idea is just to try make more tabs that can be shown and see if the slider comes up by default.

Comment: I don't want to add a scroll to my tab widget, but on the scrollArea who is on the tab widget.

Comment: My bad i misunderstood it.
Check this QAbstractScrollArea::horizontalScrollBarPolicy or 
QAbstractScrollArea::verticalScrollBarPolicy.